# GNU Make: Remove string from array with subdirectories if string contains "dirToExclude"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have a directory with a lot of subdirectories which are containing source-files. Therefore I am looking in every subdirectoy for .c-files: `cSources = $(shell dir /s /b *.c)`

However there are subdirectories with source-files I do not want to compile. If I have a variable `dirToExclude = dirName` how can I remove every string in `cSources` that contains 'dirName'?

I know that there is the `findstring`-function. But I can't figure out how to use `findstring` on every string in the array. I am looking for some way to get a nested loop like (pseudo code):

```
foreach (var in cSources)
   if (var.contains(dirToExclude))
       cSources -= var
   endif
```

Comment: How about just not using pattern matching to identify your sources?  Doing so is an antipattern.

Comment: @JohnBollinger maybe you can give me a hint to a better solution?

Comment: The conventional way is to explicitly list either the relevant source files or their corresponding object files, and to proceed from there.  If one wants to distinguish between different sets of source files then one uses multiple variables, or possibly recursive `make` with multiple makefiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know `dirToExclude` is always at the beginning of the string you can just write:

```
cSources := $(filter-out $(dirToExclude)%,$(cSources))
```

If you want to remove any filename where the string appears anywhere, you can use:

```
cSources := $(foreach S,$(cSources),$(if $(findstring $(dirToExclude),$(S)),,$(S)))
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Functions.html

Comment: The second solution pointed me in the right direction. But I guess it should be `cSources := $(foreach S,$(cSources),$(if $(findstring $(dirToExclude),$(S)),,$(S)))`

Comment: However the output is looking like it still adds an empty string to `cSources`. Do you know if it's possible to remove this aswell?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "an empty string".  Can you edit your question and cut and paste what you're seeing and why it's an issue?

Comment: If I print `cSources` it looks like: `Path Path Path     Path       Path` At the multiple spaces in a row it looks like this was a path which contains `dirToExclude`. But it is not causing any issues.

Comment: Well, if you don't want extra spaces you can run the whole thing through `$(strip ...)` (see the link to functions above).  But they probably won't hurt anything.

Comment: A million thanks for the second solution!!